# Shell script nested if

Tags: linux, shell, unix

What is wrong with the following code in shell script :

**Below code throwing unexpected else error:**

```
if [ $result -eq 0 ];
then
  echo "SFTP completed successfully to Prod Remote Server" >> $LOG_FILE
else
    errorConnectToProd=1
   if [[ $result -eq 4 || $result -eq 5 ]];
  echo "FAILED to connect to Server. " >> $LOG_FILE

   else
 echo "FAILED to SFTP to  Remote Server. " >> $LOG_FILE
   fi
fi
```

**Below line giving /usr/bin/sftp not found error:**

```
/usr/bin/sftp –v -oPort=$SFTP_PORT -b $SFTP_BATCH_FILE $SOURCE_FUNCTIONAL_ID@$REMOTE_SERVER_PROD >> $LOG_FILE 2 >> $LOG_FILE
```

Regards,

Chai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the **then** after the second if statement.

It should be

```
 if [[ $result -eq 4 || $result -eq 5 ]];
 then
   echo "FAILED to connect to Server. " >> $LOG_FILE
```

As for the second command, either sftp isn't installed or it isn't in `/usr/bin`.

Run `which sftp` to find out where it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
if [[ $result -eq 4 || $result -eq 5 ]];
```

You forget the 'then' after the if construct.

When it is not found, check if sftp is found in the path.

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors.  The syntax error is the missing `then`.  The other error is that this should be a `case` statement:

```
exec >> $LOG_FILE
case "$result" in
0)   echo "SFTP completed successfully to Prod Remote Server";;
4|5) errorConnectToProd=1
     echo "FAILED to connect to Server. ";;
*)   echo "FAILED to SFTP to  Remote Server. ";;
esac
```